# Flutter: Dismissible Widget using button

Tags: flutter

I would like to have a dismissible widget. So far I've used the `Dismissible` widget that works well when you want to swipe to dismiss.

Is there a way to dismiss by clicking a button/icon? Something like this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried AnimatedList?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the package another_flushbar. I used the predecessor flushbar which had loads of options. another_flushbar seems to have the same functionality so you might be able to achieve this

Comment: will you show the coded for flushbar that will solve the current question