# Dismissible widget: dismiss widget only when tapping a button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, dismissible

I'm trying to use the dismissible widget to get dismissed only when a button is pressed, not by swiping. Is there any way to achieve this or is that impossible to do with the Dismissible widget (or maybe I woukld have to implement my own with custom animations or something like that)?

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

I tried changing the direction setting to DismissDirection.none to prevent swiping. That works, but then I don't know how I would make it dismiss when a button is pressed. I was hoping Dismissible would have some sort of controller parameter, but it doesn't.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Dismissible(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          direction: DismissDirection.none, // This prevents it from being swiped
          child: Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          )
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {}, // I want this to somehow dismiss the Dismissible widget when this is pressed
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68866534/flutter-dismissible-widget-using-button), but the answer doesn't solve my issue, since I'm not trying to implement a notification-like widget that appears on the screen. I'm trying to dismiss a widget that is present in the body of my app.)

Comment: you want something like to just tap & make a widget invisible/dismiss? you can wrap the widget in container & set the height to 0 when button is pressed. or can use visibility widget.

Comment: Please try to implement it on your own and if you get stuck, come back here and show the code where you got stuck so we could help. take note that even if the answer is simple, no one would waste time doing the coding for you.

Comment: If I hadn't tried, I wouldn't post the question. I just don't have any idea about how to approach the problem (I'm not very experienced with Flutter). I didn't provide any code because I explained it in detail, and it's such a simple layout that I don't see how it would help anyone answer my question. Regardless, I edited it to include it.
Do you know any solution?

Comment: @TaqiTahmidTanzil That would make the widget disappear, but I want it to have the animation of Dismissible (to go to the side), and then everything below it comes up to fill its space.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dismissible(
  key: ValueKey(id),
  background: Container(
    color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.delete,
      color: Colors.white,
      size: 40,
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
  ),
  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
  confirmDismiss: (direction) => showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: ((context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: Text('Do you want to remove item from the cart'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: Text('No')),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: Text('Yes'))
          ],
        )),
  ),
  onDismissed: (direction) {
    Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).removeItem(productId);
  },
  child: Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 15,
      vertical: 4,
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: FittedBox(child: Text('\$ $price')))),
        title: Text(title),
        subtitle: Text('Total: \$ ${(price * quantity)}'),
        trailing: Text('$quantity x'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);



this might help, there's a on dismissed method which you need to apply,and inside the action list, you will get two button i.e yes or no, where you can perform your action.
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. I don't want to implement a "confirm dismiss" feature; I want to have a button on the screen that dismisses the widget, without swiping the Dismissible.